# XML Serializer still adding default namespaces even after supplying with String.Empty

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am using an XmlSerializer to create some XML. However, I am getting the www.w3.org name space stuff in my output and I do not want it. I'm my serialization code I include the line 
`xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);` that I thought was supposed to get rid of this, but it doesn't seem to be working, it only moves the namespace value into my BOM_Request section. I indcluded my code below and the output without the `xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);` and the output with it. How can I get rid of these namespaces?

Serialization code:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
String xmlRequest;

XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue = new                     
XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);
serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, request, xmlSerializerNameSpaceValue);

xmlRequest = stringWriter.ToString();
stringWriter.Close();
```

Without:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RequestHeader>
    <Field fieldName="RuleServTypeCode" value="FVAR" />
  </RequestHeader>
  <RequestPayload>
    <BOM_Request xsi:type="LossIncurredPayload" path="1" sequenceNum="1" requestSentDate="2016-06-30" validationType="LossInc" transactionId="10" decisionType="LossInc">
      <BOM_Policy path="1" sequenceNum="1" log_key="760" clm_ser_nbr="416006" />
    </BOM_Request>
  </RequestPayload>
</Request>
```

With:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request>
  <RequestHeader>
    <Field fieldName="RuleServTypeCode" value="FVAR" />
  </RequestHeader>
  <RequestPayload>
    <BOM_Request d3p1:type="LossIncurredPayload" path="1" sequenceNum="1" requestSentDate="2016-06-30" validationType="LossInc" transactionId="10" decisionType="LossInc" xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <BOM_Policy path="1" sequenceNum="1" log_key="760" clm_ser_nbr="416006" />
    </BOM_Request>
  </RequestPayload>
</Request>
```

RequestPayload class:

```
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(LossTrxPayload))]
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(PremiumPayload))]
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(LossIncurredPayload))]
public class RequestPayload
{
    [XmlElement]
    public List<Payload> BOM_Request { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does the `RequestPayload` class lool like?

Comment: @dbc Just added it

Answer (score 0):

Your `BOM_Request` has an `xsi:type` attribute to identify the type as `LossIncurredPayload`.  There's no way you can avoid specifying the `xsi` namespace here, as it's required for that attribute.

Comment: I just added the RequestPayload class to my question. Is it because I have the [XmlIncludeAttribute] tags there? This issue started popping up once I added those. Is there really no way around it?

Comment: @intA You have three different types with the same element name, so the type attribute is required to differentiate them in the resulting schema. This, for example, allows the serialiser to deserialise your payload into the correct class. If you want to get rid of it, you need to use a single class or multiple element names.